# message alert not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

this my code and the problem is that when i am sending email call form id then email is not sending when i remove form id then email is sending

Htmlcode and after html is js code
this my code and the problem is that when i am sending email call form id then email is not sending when i remove form id then email is sending

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Name *</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email *</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Company Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Subject *</label>
            <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message *</label>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

--

ajax code

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form');
form.submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        beforeSend: function() {
            form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

php code

```
               <?php


               header('Content-type: application/json');


             $status = array(
              'type'=>'success',
          'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you '
        );




         $name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));


        $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 


      $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 


    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 



      $email_from = $email;



      $email_to = 'email@email.com';//replace with your email




                   $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email .   "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;




           $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');





         echo json_encode($status);



        die;
```

Comment: can you post your html codes?

Comment: Could you include the code that actually sends the email (i.e. the server-side code that your form is submitting to)?

Comment: When you remove the ID, the handler doesn't work, and the form is submitted the regular way. Your form probably sends something to the server. The ajax call does ***not*** !

Comment: @kiro112 please check the html code.

Comment: also show php code?

Comment: the `form` is already sending a `post` request and you still doing `ajax` when it triggered submit. if im not mistaken the backend is written in `php` ?

Comment: Please format your code properly, without the spaces. It's an eyesore to try to fix. Also, separate your two files (if you know how).

Comment: @kiro112 yes backend is in php

Comment: is your ajax response really a json object? cause if not this data.message will cause error. try console.log(data); before  form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut(); . show me the ajax response using the Network dev tools

Comment: @DonaldWu please check php code

Comment: avoid to use ``@`` in php

Comment: The PHP clearly works, as regular form submits work, but the ajax call is making a GET request with absolutely no data at all.

Comment: Did you try to put ``success`` function inside ``$.ajax``? Also try to put ``error`` function to see the error...

Comment: I see you use ``echo json_encode($status);``..Try ``var data = $.parseJSON(data);`` in ``$.ajax``

Comment: I think he just forgot to parse the data inside his done function

Answer (score 1):

This is what your ajax call should look like

```
$('#main-contact-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');

    $.ajax({
        url        : $(this).attr('action'),
        data       : $(this).serialize(),
        dataType   : 'json',
        type       : 'POST',
        beforeSend : function() {
            form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure your ajax response which is

```
function(data)
```

is really an object variable
because if not this code will not execute because of error of data.message

```
form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

also kindly check your network status check the response of that ajax request
using the dev tools F12

- UPDATED ANSWER BELOW

so your response is json but still need to be parse in your javascript.
 **SOLUTION:**  Parse your ajax response to make it json object

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you don't send your form data with the ajax-call.
Like adeneo wrote, you only have to add one line to your code.

```
data       : $(this).serialize(),
```

Setting the data-type is relevant, because the destination needs to know in which format the data is sent.

Try using the Jquery-POST-function. It looks much better in the code.